# Alias for associated type of supertrait

Tags: rust

I have the following trait:

```
use std::ops::Index;

trait Map: Index<<Self as Map>::Key> {
    type Key;
}
```

`Index` has the associated type `Output`. I semantically want this type, but I don't like the name `Output` in my API. Thus I would like to add an alias for that type.

I tried this (the same syntax for normal type aliases):

```
trait Map: Index<<Self as Map>::Key> {
    type Key;
    type Value = <Self as Index<Self::Key>>::Output;
}
```

However, this results in an error:

```
error[E0658]: associated type defaults are unstable (see issue #29661)
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         type Value = <Self as Index>::Output;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From [the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29661) I could gather that this syntax is apparently used for associated types that can be overwritten by implementors. But I don't want implementors to overwrite this type, I always want `Map::Value == Map::Output`.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [associated item RFC](https://github.com/aturon/rfcs/blob/associated-items/active/0000-associated-items.md) states:

> Type parameters to traits can either be "inputs" or "outputs":
>
> - Inputs. An "input" type parameter is used to determine which impl to use.
> - Outputs. An "output" type parameter is uniquely determined by the impl, but plays no role in   selecting the impl.

The RFC also clarifies trait matching by:

> - Treating all trait type parameters as input types, and
> - Providing associated types, which are output types.

From these descriptions it is clear that an associated type is by design in control by the `impl`, so it is not possible to block implementors from overwriting the type.

A workaround for obtaining some form of control over the implementor may be to define a default method that uses the associated type, for example:

```
pub trait Map: Index<<Self as Map>::Key> {
    type Key;
    type Value = <Self as Index<<Self as Map>::Key>>::Output;

    #[doc(hidden)]
    fn invalid_operation() -> Option<&'static <Self as Index<<Self as Map>::Key>>::Output> {
        None
    }
}
```

Now for the implementors is not more possible to simply override the default `Value` type because the default method `invalid_operation` no longer typecheck.

Note also the `doc(hidden)` feature that strips the default method from the docs.

The hidden method name may be chosen to convey some information.
For the above example, the implementor get the error message:

```
 error[E0399]: the following trait items need to be reimplemented as `Value` was overridden: `invalid_operation`
```

As you already know, assigning default associated types is not permitted in current stable Rust, a nightly version must be used and the feature has to be enabled with:

```
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]
```

Comment: Very interesting, I wasn't aware of the behavior of default associated types with provided methods. I found [another way to enforce the type restriction](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c61fe3fe296a98699e989c37e5b287e5&version=nightly&mode=debug), I think. But yeah, unstable and a bit hacky. Maybe I just won't do it like that ;-)